# What does "Women like guys who play the dance." mean?

Tags: vocabulary

"Women like guys who play the dance."

What does "playing the dance" mean in this context?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the source for the quotation?  Slang varies widely from place-to-place and over the years, so knowing when and where the quotation appeared will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't heard of this sentence before.

But I have heard of

> Women like guys who can dance.

or

> Women like guys who aren't afraid to dance.

I think your sentence just means pretty much the same/similar thing. Like a guy who goes out on the dance floor and has fun (plays).

Supposedly women sometimes/often equate a man's dancing skills to how good in bed they'd be.